# Recommended fasts during Shaban

Tags: sawm

Can someone highlight and explain in detail the various fasts that are recommended during the month of Shaban based on the authentic hadeeth?

Answer (score 1):

The rule is to fast the first half of Sha'ban, and among the wisdom in this is getting used to fasting so when Ramadan comes it is a bit easier, so when the half of Sha'ban comes then we shouldn't fast.

> إِذَا انْتَصَفَ شَعْبَانُ فَلاَ تَصُومُوا
>
> When the middle of Sha'ban comes, do not fast

[Sunan Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/14/25)

I am unsure whether this is what you where referring to by "various fasts".

Comment: Shaikh Muhammad Salah talks about the various fasts in Sha'ban in the latter part of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMTt_qrzOcw